# How to update metadata of customfield through ToolingAPI

Tags: tooling-api

I am able to do PATCH to developername by
/services/data/v30.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/{FieldID}

with body: 
{
 "developername":"abc"
}

however, it's failed when I tried to update any metadata like

{
  "Metadata" : {
    "trackHistory" : true
  }
}

message: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support:

Comment: This post [Is it possible to update custom field metadata via the tooling api?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18421/is-it-possible-to-update-custom-field-metadata-via-the-tooling-api) says this is a known issue (=bug) in Nov 2013 so it is possible that it is still broken. It suggests using the metadata API instead.

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been fixed by salesforce in summer release but can you post the Gack  or the stack trace id, which is the error id.

I am sure you are using the json format perfectly fine.Please ensure that you are using the full name too in the body.

{
"DeveloperName": "Address",
"FullName": "House__c.Address__c",
"Metadata": {
"label": "Address",
"type": "Text",
"length": 120
}
}

Comment: Tried { "DeveloperName": "abc", "FullName": "01Io00000005LHN.abc", "Metadata": { "label": "testabc" }}   got INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE  message: Metadata API exception   errorCode: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE          Tried { "DeveloperName": "abc", "Metadata": { "label": "testabc" }} message: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 671499041-2789 (-1657627855)

Comment: { "DeveloperName": "abc", "FullName": "01Io00000005LHN.abc__c", "Metadata": { "label": "testabc" }}  same error

Comment: David, Are you doing this in a summer release sandbox or your production, which is on Spring release.

Comment: I am doing it in the Partner Developer Edition created from partnerforce. Thanks!